# Cutom Keyboard On windows CE

Tags: compact-framework, keyboard, controls

I have coded a custom keyboard on CF 35. , Windows CE 6.0 .
It is created and added to form on BaseForm and all forms inherit from this one.
So my problem is : custom keyboard takes 1-2 second to be created and located on every form load.
how can i get solve this?

Here is the Constructor of Keyboard

```
public KeyBoard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panelNumeric.SendToBack();
        panelNumeric.Visible = false;
        this.Visible = false;

        //Click event
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
            this.Controls[i].Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);

        panelNumeric.Click -= ButtonClick;

        for (int i = 0; i < panelNumeric.Controls.Count; i++)
            panelNumeric.Controls[i].Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);

        //Caps Lock
        btnListForCaps = new List<Control>(){btnQ,btnW,btnE,btnR,btnT,btnY,btnU,btnI,btnO,btnP,btnP,btnTRG,btnTRU,btnA,btnS,btnD,btnF,btnG,btnH,btnJ,btnK,btnL,btnTRS,btnTRI,btnZ,btnX,btnC,btnV,btnB,btnN,btnM,btnTRO,btnTRC};ButtonClick(btnShift, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. 
i added a new form and locate keyboard buttons on it.
Create keyboard form on application load and declare it as a static global variable.
Call "GlobalParameters.Keyboard.CustomShow();" on each form i need.
hope it helps